# Failure in conversion type

Tags: sql, type-conversion

```
Select * from tabella
where 
aa not like (%DIV%)
```

Please tell me why it doesn't work and it returns the following error:

> 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'OTB018926' to
>   data type int'

Comment: Please give us your table definition.

Comment: Also, which dialect of SQl. T-SQL? MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select * from tabella where aa not like '%DIV%'
```

You are missing the single quotes in query.

Comment: @user3197365 can you describe table structure of table `tabella`

Comment: What do you mean? Structure in what sense: i tried many different solutions like cast (reasoncode AS VARCHAR(15)) not like '%DIV%' or convert (VARCHAR, reasoncode) not like '%DIV%' but the error is always the same

Comment: @user3197365 by table structure I mean the definition of table. So please describe Fields in your table with datatypes.

Comment: Yes I know but I didn't declare any datatype: the query Is only this I written above. What Can i DO?

Comment: You can SHOW US THE COMPLETE SQL. Seriously, the only way I can get the error is by writing something like `fieldname+1` in a query, where `fieldname` is a varchar. So in other words, your example above is not complete.